# Multiple tables query for search function in rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, performance

I have a rails app with DB:
[image]

I'm doing the search applied job function:

[image]

In controller, i did the email part like:

```
class AdminsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_admin!

  def applies
    @city = City.all.map(&:name)
    @industry = Industry.all.map(&:name)
    if applied_params
      @apply_jobs = ApplyJob.includes(:job, cv_attachment: :blob).where(email: applied_params[:email])
                            .page(params[:page]).per(Job::JOB_PER_PAGE)
    else
      @apply_jobs = ApplyJob.includes(:job, cv_attachment: :blob).all
                            .page(params[:page]).per(Job::JOB_PER_PAGE)
    end
  end

  private
  def applied_params
    params.permit(:email, :city, :industry, :date)
  end
end
```

search form like:

```
= form_with(url: admin_applies_jobs_path, method: :get, local: true) do |f|
    .row.mb-2.form-group 
      .col-2
        = f.label :email, 'Email'
      .col-10
        = f.text_field :email, class: 'form-control'
    
    .row.mb-2.form-group 
      .col-2
        = f.label :city, 'City'
      .col-10
        = f.select :city, options_for_select(@city.map {|c| [c, c]}, params[:city]), class:"form-select bg-light h-100"

    .row.mb-2.form-group 
      .col-2
        = f.label :industry, 'Industry'
      .col-10
        = f.select :industry, options_for_select(@industry.map {|c| [c, c]}, params[:city]), class:"form-select bg-light h-100"
    = f.submit 'Search', class: 'btn btn-primary w-25 my-4 btn-height',data: { disable_with: false }
```

How can I query both city and industry?

Comment: Can you add an output of `applied_params` and show how output looks like when you submit the form?

Comment: You just need to join to cities_jobs and filter for the city, same with industries_jobs

Comment: @Jokūbas params may or may not be present. Depends on when we fill out the search form

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work if you are passing the ids as the params which you should be to avoid joining to two more tables.

```
ApplyJob.includes(:job, cv_attachment: :blob)
        .joins('INNER JOIN cities_jobs ON cities_jobs.job_id = apply_jobs.job_id')
        .joins('INNER JOIN industries_jobs ON industries_jobs.job_id = apply_jobs.job_id')
        .where('email = ? AND cities_jobs.city_id = ? AND industries_jobs.industry_id = ?', applied_params[:email], applied_params[:city], applied_params[:industry])
        .page(params[:page]).per(Job::JOB_PER_PAGE)
```

Comment: e.g. I want to find only email, maybe this code doesn't work