# How to conditionally apply where clause in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, performance, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I have the code:

```
ApplyJob.includes(:job, cv_attachment: :blob)
        .joins('INNER JOIN cities_jobs ON cities_jobs.job_id = apply_jobs.job_id')
        .joins('INNER JOIN industries_jobs ON industries_jobs.job_id = apply_jobs.job_id')
               .where('email = ? AND cities_jobs.city_id = ?
                       AND industries_jobs.industry_id = ?
                       AND apply_jobs.created_at BETWEEN ? AND ?',
                       applied_params[:email],
                       applied_params[:city],
                       applied_params[:industry],
                       d_start,
                       d_end)
```

```
def applied_params
  params.permit(:email, :city, :industry, :date_start, :date_end)
end
```

how to ignore clause inside `where` when corresponding `params` are `blank`. If using `if else` or `case when` the code will be very long

Example: if `applied_params[:email]` is not present, `email = ?` will not be mentioned.

Answer (score 3):

You can conditionally chain `where` clauses based on provided input:

```
query = ApplyJob.includes(:job, cv_attachment: :blob)
                .joins('INNER JOIN cities_jobs ON cities_jobs.job_id = apply_jobs.job_id')
                .joins('INNER JOIN industries_jobs ON industries_jobs.job_id = apply_jobs.job_id')

query = query.where(email: applied_params[:email]) if applied_params[:email].present?
query = query.where(cities_jobs: { city_id: applied_params[:city] }) if applied_params[:city].present?
```

and so on.

Chaining `where` multiple times is not going to fire sql queries immediately, instead constructing a single query.

Another approach would be to initiate a mapping like:

```
mapping = { 
  ?: { email: applied_params[:email] }, 
  cities_jobs: { city_id: applied_params[:city] },
  industries_jobs: { industry_id: applied_params[:industry] },
  apply_jobs: { created_at: (d_start..d_end if d_start && d_end) }
}.filter { |_, value| value.compact.presence }
```

and then pass it to `where` method:

```
query.where(mapping)
```

Comment: If you use that way, you have to use a lot of conditional statements

Comment: yes, but there is not much to be done to omit that. maybe you can declare a mapping like `{ email: { email: applied_params[:email] }, cities_jobs: { city_id: applied_params[:city] }}`, filter it by presence of the deepest value and then pass to `where`, but mapping itself is going to be quite thick as well

Comment: this is a supplement to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69674227/multiple-tables-query-for-search-function-in-rails-app/69681247#69681247). Can you take a look and help me?